# Как получить сырую json строку из html(request)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, request

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
url = 'https://sbis.ru/contragents/7726722400'
r = requests.get(url).text
```

При выполнении этого кода в переменную r возвращается текст страницы где есть javascript с json. Строка почти 90тыс символов, для примера вставил кусок:

```
window.componentOptions = '{"cfg-wcwhlv6os1569436653574":{"className":"sbis_ru-content_scrollContainer","stickyContainer":false,"esc":false,"data-component":"SBIS3.CONTROLS/ScrollContainer
```

Этим кодом я нашел всю подстроку json в строке:

```
start = r.find(r"window.componentOptions") + 27
finish = r.find("</script>", start) - 3
r = r[start:finish]
```

но в момент преобразования json в словарь:

```
y = json.loads(r)
```

Выходит ошибка, хотя если вывести значение переменной в консоль и скопировать скрипт то операция завершается корректно. При сравнении в переменной до отображения в консоль символов немного больше.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/keshs/PycharmProjects/CDEK/sbis_tenzor.py", line 16, in <module>
    y = json.loads(r)
  File "C:\Users\keshs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\keshs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\keshs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 885 (char 884)
```

У меня получилось выполнить этот скрипт заменив в requests.text на requests.get(url).content.decode("unicode-escape"). Но тогда текст становиться в кодировке ISO-8859-15, русский текст отображается "кракозябрами" и преобразовать строку в utf-8 я не смог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в двойных слешах в строках вида `\\"`. Т.к. в том javascript в `window.componentOptions` находилась **строка** с json, то понадобилось экранировать и сам слеш, но в самом json достаточно одного слеша для экранирования кавычек.

```
import json
import re

import requests


def get_component_options(text: str) -> dict:
    m = re.search("window\.componentOptions = '({.+?})';", text)
    if not m:
        raise Exception("""Не получилось найти 'window.componentOptions = '""")

    text = m.group(1)
    # Замена двойных слешей на одинарные
    text = text.replace("\\\\", "\\")
    return json.loads(text)


url = 'https://sbis.ru/contragents/7726722400'
rs = requests.get(url)

data = get_component_options(rs.text)
print(data)
# {'cfg-wcwhlv6os1569436653574': {'className': 'sbis_ru-content_scrollContainer', 'stickyContainer': False, ...
```